# Configuring an IP address to my domain

Tags: dns, ip, hosting

Sorry this may be a basic question.

I have a domain name onebyinfinity.co.nz and I want it to point to an ip address 203.124.98.229. I have set the A record in my DNS Server to 203.124.98.229. However when I run ping onebyinfinity.co.nz, it says "host not found"

I tried NSLookup here - http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=onebyinfinity.co.nz&type=255&server=ns2.dnspackage.com&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=0&go.y=9 and I can see the IP address in the A record.

Is there anything I need to do to enable ping to work.

Thanks

Comment: When did you made the DNS record changes? I can ping onebyinfinity.co.nz and it resolves to 203.124.98.229 - This is done from my workplace in Australia. So it already resolves for me.

Comment: Thanks Darius, the last change was made about 3 hours back. I have been trying various methods since the past 24 horus. Do you think my ISP or my local PC would have cached it?

Comment: Propagated all the way to the US now.

Comment: Assuming you are in Windows try ipconfig /flushdns and try again. Or use a different dns server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Fine Bro!

```
C:\Users\DMRC>ping onebyinfinity.co.nz

Pinging onebyinfinity.co.nz [203.124.98.229] with 32 byt
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=305ms TTL=112
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=306ms TTL=112
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=306ms TTL=112
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=307ms TTL=112

Ping statistics for 203.124.98.229:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 305ms, Maximum = 307ms, Average = 306ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fine on my end... maybe something on your end is messed up, or you tried pinging it before the DNS Records you added propagated?

```
C:\Users\user>nslookup onebyinfinity.co.nz
Server:  DD-WRT
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    onebyinfinity.co.nz
Address:  203.124.98.229


C:\Users\user>ping onebyinfinity.co.nz

Pinging onebyinfinity.co.nz [203.124.98.229] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=275ms TTL=114
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=265ms TTL=114
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=262ms TTL=114
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=262ms TTL=114

Ping statistics for 203.124.98.229:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 262ms, Maximum = 275ms, Average = 266ms

C:\Users\user>ping 203.124.98.229

Pinging 203.124.98.229 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=265ms TTL=114
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=266ms TTL=114
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=259ms TTL=114
Reply from 203.124.98.229: bytes=32 time=259ms TTL=114

Ping statistics for 203.124.98.229:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 259ms, Maximum = 266ms, Average = 262ms

C:\Users\user>
```